# Yii data provider pagination how to make human url?

Tags: php, yii, pagination, yii-url-manager, cactivedataprovider

I am setting the pagination variable with the following:

```
 $dp->pagination = array('pageVar'=>'page');
```

And adding to the main config rule with this:

```
'/myrule/page/<page:\d+>' => 'controller/action'
```

URLs `/myrule/page/1` and `/myrule/?page=1` work. However, pagination generates `/myrule/?page=1`. How do I get URLs like `/myrule/page/1` from pagination?

Answer (score 2):

Resolve: displace rule higher on the list - that  rule worked before the other.